# How to replace a list of multiple strings in all the columns of a python data frame?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

I consider myself as a beginner to midlevel python programmer.
I was surprised that I could not find a simple solution for my question on google. I was trying to replace a list of multiple strings in a python dataframe's all the columns. I did the straight forward way (below) and it works fine.

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('.', '')
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(' ','')
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('(','_')
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(')','')
```

I wanted to reduce the number of lines and code everything in one line like how I can use multiple .replace() when I try to replace multiple strings in a sentence.
For ex,

```
txt = 'welcome to metaverse_'
txt.replace('w', 'W').replace('m', 'M').replace('_', '!')

out : 'WelcoMe to Metaverse!'
```

Is there anyway I can reduce the repetitive code and just use one line to replace multiple strings in all the columns?

Note: I have 10s of columns, and not all the columns have all the strings I want to replace

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"[ .)]", "", regex=True).str.replace(r"(", "_", regex=False)`

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr_dict = {'.': '', ' ': '', '(': '_', ')': ''}
df.columns=df.columns.str.translate(df.columns.str.maketrans(tr_dict))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I get the following error when I tried this.

`AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'maketranslate' `

Comment: @Bhanu It is actually `maketranslate`. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a dictionary with replace but since you are replacing some 'special' regex characters you'll need to escape them

```py
df = df.replace({'\\.':'',' ':'','\\(':'_','\\)':''}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but does this apply for columns as I want to change replace the strings in the columns names?

Comment: Your question wasn't clear, I assumed you wanted to replace the values in all the columns of the dataframe, not change the column names.